# Restrict the WooCommerce API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I need to allow access to a WooCommerce API, but give READ access to the Products only. The API works fine currently but is a security concern as it can access all information regarding customers and orders.

I have found a plugin that can do it, but it is barely used and is over 4 years since an update. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-api-lockdown/

Has anyone got any suggestions here? I've searched the internet and can't find another solution. I'm assuming a function could be written but I don't know where to start.

Many thanks
Dan

Comment: I have the exact same problem, do you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the keys you can choose to only make have it access to read. Or do you want further restrictions on what it can read?

Comment: Is that possible to do@TimonAndries ? I have a similar situation...